# Cant figure out why this function never returns the proper result

Tags: c

The function below is supposed to find out when there are two duplicate cards in this card game I am working on.

```
int duplicate (struct card hand[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, duplicate = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
        {
            if (hand[i].suit == hand[j].suit && hand[i].face == hand[j].face)
            {
                duplicate++;
            }
        }
    }
    return duplicate;
}
```

I cannot figure out why, but when the value of cards within the hand are the same it never adds to the number of duplicate cards.

Im convinced it must be something obvious but I dont see it.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using a debugger to step through it and that will show you the obvious.

Comment: Maybe you could include the class declaration of hand. Are you checking exact duplicates of the cards in your testing?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  It must be that the parameter being passed isn't what you think it is?  Maybe print it out inside the function....

Comment: Why would there ever be exact duplicate cards in the same hand? Are you dealing from multiple decks? One deck contains only one of each card.

Comment: The outer loop should be one less than the inner loop or else there is a waste of some miliseconds and electricity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let us know what the types for `suit` and `hand` are for `struct card` - that could affect how they should be compared (in particular if they're pointers).

Also, you should let us know what data you're passing in, what result you're getting and what you expect. For example, if you pass in a hand of 5 cards, two of which are the same, it looks to me like you'll get 1 returned (which might be what you expect, but you might be expecting 2 - I don't know). This is because you don't count the card pointed to by `i`.  Again - whether you should depends on what result you want/need.

But another example that almost certainly isn't what you want is if you pass in a hand of 5 cards all of which are the same.  You might be expecting a result of 5 (or maybe 4), but what you'll get is 10, because when:

```
i == 0, you count the 4 dupes
i == 1, you count the next 3 cards as dupes again
i == 2, the next 2 get counted again,

etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess not knowing anything about the input or the definition of *card*, is that the `==` operator isn't doing what you think for *suit* or *face*. Are those primitives that can be compared out of the box or pointers/objects that need special attention?